# Writing _rendered_ PHP to HTML file

Tags: php, html

Having probs here.

I need to write the output of a PHP script to an HTML page to then be processed by DOMPDF so I can make a nice little PDF for some friends to use.

When I use file_get_contents to get the contents of a "donor" PHP script, it does that - literally.  It grabs the unevaluated PHP and holds it for me to do as I wish.

I need the PHP script to RUN, then take the output and file_put_contents it somewhere.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ideally you can configure the PHP script so that instead of writing its contents it builds a giant string and returns it. That way you can simply call a function and get back a string with the information you need.

If the target script is out of your control, you might work around it with something like:

```
ob_start();
include('script.php');
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Elegant.  Simple.  Something ELSE I had no clue about.  Thanks, VOTEY!

Answer (score 2):

Call it through http to make it run.

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost/my/script/file.php");
```

alternatively, run it from the command line:

```
php -f /path/to/my/script/file.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Two quick solutions.  The first is to setup the PHP script to run from a url, and then user `file_get_contents` or the `curl` functions to download the page.  This will give you a string with the correct content.

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://example.com/myscript.php');
```

The second is to use `include` and output buffering.  Output buffering takes any `echo` or `print` statments, and stores their content in memory rather then outputting to the browser/screen.

```
ob_start(); //start output buffering
include("myscript.php"); //script will run in the current context, but output will be stored in memory
$string = ob_get_clean(); //stored output will be fetched into $string, and buffering ended
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a few different ways:

1) Fetch the script through it's URL (through the web browser) instead of the file path.

2) Use [eval](http://php.net/eval)

3) Use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) and include the script into the current one. Example:

```
ob_start();
include('script.php');
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

4) Run it from the commandline using `shell_exec('php -f script.php');`